# How to insert a variable type as a parameter function?

Tags: c++, function, parameters

I have the following function:

```
int readAndCheck () {
    int n;
    while (n < 2) {
        try {
            cout << "Please insert an integer bigger than one: ";
            string check = "";
            cin >> check;
            n = boost::lexical_cast<int>(check);
        } catch (boost::bad_lexical_cast&) {
            cout << "Error!\n";
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

I want to generalize the function so that it can output any request to the user and check for any type. But I know  the following is not possible:

```
checktype readAndCheck (string request, checktype) {
    checktype n;
    while (n < 2) {
        try {
            cout << request;
            string check = "";
            cin >> check;
            n = boost::lexical_cast<checktype>(check);
        } catch (boost::bad_lexical_cast&) {
            cout << "Error!\n";
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

1. How can I create a variable that holds a type like checktype (is it possible)?
2. What's the way around to create a generalized readAndCheck function for every possible value of checktype?

I'm asking this because it seems tedious to have to create a function for each checktype.

**SOLUTION**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

template<typename CheckType>
CheckType readAndCheck(std::string request, CheckType n)
{
    try {
        std::cout << request;
        std::string check = "";
        std::cin >> check;
        n = boost::lexical_cast<CheckType>(check);
    } catch (boost::bad_lexical_cast&) {
        std::cout << "Error!\n";
    }
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    while (a < 2)
        a = readAndCheck("Please insert a integer bigger than one: ", a);
    std::cout << a << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is tagged C++ and yet you seem to have no idea that templates exist. What's up with that?

Comment: I've started studing C++ like a week ago. I just looked what templates are. Interesting, but could you elaborate a little please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the several pillars of C++ is a feature called `template`s, and one of their (many) primary reasons for existing is precisely to ease situations like this, where otherwise very repetitive code would be required.

Documentation is more than abundant, but in brief, the idea is you declare a `template`d class or function, with generic types or integral (including pointers) *template arguments* as placeholders for real types or values. The `template` is not a type until you *instantiate* this template with all required arguments, creating an actual type/code from it.

You instantiate a `template` through a declaration for a class ( *e.g.* `MyTemplate<Arguments> myInstance{ctor_args}` ), or for functions, a declaration or call (*e.g.* `myFunc<OptionalArguments>(func_args)`; see also below). The arguments you supply during instantiation are substituted (in a *far* more sophisticated way than macros!) for the placeholders specified earlier, finally creating a concrete template class (and associated code) or function, which contains or acts upon the specified types/integral values.

For more complex cases, templates can be explicitly *specialised*, to act differently for different sets of template arguments. That is, you could specify one generic template that would handle most types, but explicitly specialise for a given set of arguments if other code is required there.

*Template functions* often don't need you to explicitly specify the template arguments, if those can be unambiguously inferred from the call site (*i.e.* by the type of a function argument). If template arguments cannot be deduced (*e.g.* there's no corresponding function argument) then you must supply them when calling, in `<Brackets>` like you would when instantiating a template class.

I can't test code right now (nor do I know how `boost::lexical_cast` works), but your simple case would be *something* like this:

```
// Return a new instance - can't deduce type, must specify at call site
// Call like: auto checked{ readAndCheck<YourType>(yourRequest) };
template<typename T_CheckType>
T_CheckType readAndCheck(std::string request)
{
    // assumes T_CheckType not initialised with gibberish:
    T_CheckType n;

    while (n < 2) { // assumes T_CheckType convertible to int
        try {
            std::cout << request;
            std::string check = "";
            std::cin >> check;
            n = boost::lexical_cast<T_CheckType>(check);
        } catch (boost::bad_lexical_cast&) {
            std::cout << "Error!\n"; // may return invalid instance
        }
    }
    return n;
}

// XOR

// Write result to passed output parameter - enables deduction from arg #2
// Call like: readAndCheck(yourRequest, yourOutputParameter);
template<typename T_CheckType>
void readAndCheck(std::string request, T_CheckType &output_checked)
{
    // reinitialise output_checked here if required

    while (output_checked < 2) { // assumes T_CheckType convertible to int
        try {
            std::cout << request;
            std::string check = "";
            std::cin >> check;
            output_checked = boost::lexical_cast<T_CheckType>(check);
        } catch (boost::bad_lexical_cast&) {
            std::cout << "Error!\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise all that documentation about learning templates should help you out ;-)

Comment: when I run it, the first note is: `couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T_CheckType’` :/

Comment: In your latest draft of `readAndCheck()`, T_CheckType can't be deduced, seeing as there is no function parameter from which to deduce it. So, you must either change the function's signature to be deducible (_e.g._ via an output parameter) or just specify the desired type explicitly when calling: `auto checked{ readAndCheck<WhateverType>(request) };`. Added some untested illustrations to my post. I think this is fairly basic, so a tutorial about templates would explain it better than back-and-forth in this thread - or than my explanatory skills ;-)